# SP16 - After install webpart missing under development folder

Tags: sharepoint-server, folder, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, missing

When i install SPFx webpart in my **on-prem server**. In Developer site i want to add this webpart in page.

Folder [**Under development**](https://youtu.be/LGLMxnmHk6U?t=15m12s) is missing.

[image]

Comment: Check with your installation mayb you may installed in any other site collection.

Comment: Solved - Site collection template must be "Publishing portal"